# font-family Verdana-Bold not supported in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, webfonts

If I set the font-family to `Verdana-Bold`, it doesn't work in FF (version 18) but Chrome (version 24) is fine.

If I change the font-family to `Verdana`, it works in both browsers.

Similarly, `CourierNewPS-BoldMT`, doesn't work, but `Courier` does.

Does anyone know of a generic solution to solve this? like a JS or a CSS technique that could convert the fonts specific to the browser?

http://jsfiddle.net/skUxK/4/

Here's the description of the use case:
I have a HTML5 app, that also has a equivalent windows desktop version, a mac app and a iOS and android app.

All these apps can make changes to a text, and then store those in a XML file.This file can be then be loaded any app.

Comment: Hi, if you're setting font-family, did you put quotes `'Verdana-Bold'`? You're also calling the browser to use the system fonts, if the system doesn't have the font, then the font won't work. The answers below are very helpful to address cross-browser font rendering.

Comment: @VKen  It works OK on the same machine on Chrome with Verdana-Bold

Comment: When I test it, Verdana-Bold does not work on Chrome either. It is not a font family name, so why should it? Are you actually using a *downloadable* font that you have named that way?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Try the http://jsfiddle.net/skUxK/ . and see the difference in Chrome and FF. Maybe these fonts are not available on your machine. I am using mountain lion.

Comment: @sbr, I see no difference. There is no font family Verdana-Bold, and my machine has no such typeface either (but it has “Verdana Lihavoitu”). I think your real problem is using a bold typeface when using a downloadable font, and a bold typeface of Verdana as a backup, but the question does not describe this.

Comment: @sbr I've seen some of google's webfonts stylesheet [here](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,400italic,700,700italic). If you look closely, different font-weight is being grouped together as one family of font. I'm guessing that firefox has grouped the system fonts under `Verdana` font family for `Verdana-Bold`. You'll have to research more into that to find out Firefox's actual implementation.

Comment: @VKen Thanks. Yes, actually it seems that Google Chrome is able to map the "Verdana-Bold" (and  maybe other similar naming) to make it 'Verdana'. But not FF .

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Chrome v75 in Windows10, but works in Edge  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119997/chrome-doesnt-support-font-family-arial-bold

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to use the bold version of a font, use the `font-weight` property.

```
font-family: verdana;
font-weight: bold;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `@font-face` so that [every single browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface) can display the exact same font.

For more information: http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url('mybeautifulfont.otf');
}

body{
    font-family: 'MyFont', 'Verdana-Bold', 'Verdana';
}
```

---

If you only just want bold text, then:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Verdana-Bold', 'Verdana';
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Heres the thing. I am working on a app that has a equivalent windows desktop version, a mac app, a html5 app and a iOS app. All these apps can make changes to a text, and thus store those in a XML file. This file can be loaded then by any app. This technique works, but not for legacy apps running.

Comment: The question was about Verdana-Bold. Do you think it may be legally used as a downloadable font?

Comment: Actually you can just do this if you want bold text `font-weight: bold;`.

Comment: @Derek I can make it to work for this specific case. It will be something like, if font is 'Verdana-Bold', make it Verdana and then set the font-weight. But again , for "CourierNewPS-BoldMT", I need to do this mapping..and so on. I am trying to get a generic solution

Comment: "CourierNewPS-BoldMT" and "Verdana-Bold" is not a generic solution. Web-safe font-names and original css 'font-*' properties is a generic solution.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, bolded Verdana displays fine on Firefox. [image]